# How to avoid overlaying annotations?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some annotation in a `geom_histogram()` ggplot. See image below. These annotations are the count of the histogram for each bin, each group. However, I don't know how to distance the different annotations when the counts are similar. I only know to fix the annotation with `vjust` or `hjust` but I wonder if there's a relative way. I don't think an example is necessary. Probably just looking at my code will be easy for someone more experienced.

This is the code I have used:

```
bind_rows(
  RN_df %>% mutate(type='RN'),
  RVNM_df %>% mutate(type='RVM')
) %>% group_by(hash) %>% 
  summarise(n_eps = n(), genre, type) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = n_eps, fill = genre)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  stat_count(aes(y=..count..,label=..count.., colour = genre),geom="text",vjust= -1, hjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

This is my output image:

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_text_repel` from `ggrepel`:

```r
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(x = n_eps, fill = genre)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ..count..), stat = 'count', 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), direction = 'y') +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]